# C++ : declaring in if/else : var not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, gcc, variable-declaration

I don't understand something in C++, gcc doesn't like how do I proceed.
I did :

```
    if (!fModeMdi)
            MyFirstClass* main = (MyFirstClass*) fMaino;
    else
            MySecondClass* main = (MySecondClass*) fMdio;
    ...
    ...
    int i = main->GetNum();
```

and I get this error :

```
file.C:211:16: warning: unused variable 'main' [-Wunused-variable]
file.C:213:15: warning: unused variable 'main' [-Wunused-variable]
file.C:219:9: error: 'main' was not declared in this scope
```

I cannot declare `main` in my header, because his type depends on `fModeMdi` boolean.
How can I solve this please ?

Comment: Is there an inheritance hierarchy for the two classes?

Comment: So should provided the classes definitions, as well as some context in which "main" is used. We can't be guessing how your code is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

How about defining the variable before the if statement, and assigning it inside of it?

```
MyFirstClass* main = 0; // use nullptr if you have access to a C++11 compiler

if (!fModeMdi)
    main = (MyFirstClass*) fMaino;
else
    main = (MySecondClass*) fMdio;
```

Since you defined it inside the if statement, after it, the variable already went out of scope and can no longer be referenced.

Comment: What if `MySecondClass` is NOT derived from `MyFirstClass` (directly or indirectly)?

Comment: As long as we can assume it's OK to cast a `MySecondClass *` to a `MyFirstClass *`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I assumed that, since OP is using 2 variables named the same way, those types were compatible. If he provided those classes definitions, maybe another approach could be used.

Comment: @mfontanini: Note that c-style cast may not work here. What you need here is `dynamic_cast` if objects involved are polymorphic classes.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, using templates(your solution) was the right thing to do if those classes were unrelated(and is also valid if they're related). However, it should be OP who clarifies, not us guessing. I just fixed his compilation error, which was produced by the fact that "main" went out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

If `MyFirstClass` and `MySecondClass` are *related* through inheritance, then you can do what @unkulunkulu suggested in his answer.

However, if `MyFirstClass` and `MySecondClass` are *unrelated* classes, then you could use template as:

```
if (!fModeMdi)
{
    do_work(static_cast<MyFirstClass*>(fMaino));
}
else
{
    do_work(static_cast<MySecondClass*>(fMaino));
}
```

where `do_work` is a function template, implemented as:

```
template<typename T>
void do_work(T *obj)
{
    int i = obj->GetNum();

    //do rest of the work here....
}
```

Note that this template solution would work even if they're related!!

Answer (score 2):

Assign the value of i with in the loop.

```
int i;
if (!fModeMdi){
        MyFirstClass* main = (MyFirstClass*) fMaino;
        i = main->GetNum();
}else{
        MySecondClass* main = (MySecondClass*) fMdio;
        i = main->GetNum();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work. In c++ the scope of a variable is inside the bracket { }, that is it is only recognized inside the bracket. Once you get out, the program has no idea about it.

```
MyFirstClass* main =0; 
MySecondClass* main2 =0; 

if (!fModeMdi)
            main = (MyFirstClass*) fMaino;
    else
            main2 = (MySecondClass*) fMdio;
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a statically-typed language, at this line

```
    int i = main->GetNum();
```

the compiler has to know the type of `main` at compile time (statically, hence the name). You cannot make type of `main` depend on some value `fModeMdi`, which is known only at runtime. If each of your classes contain a method `GetNum` and others, which you use after the `if` statement, you can consider moving them to a base class like this:

```
class MyBaseClass {
public:
    virtual int GetNum() = 0;
}

class MyFirstClass : public MyBaseClass {
    // ...
};


class MySecondClass : public MyBaseClass {
    // ...
};

MyBaseClass* main = 0;
if (!fModeMdi)
            main = (MyFirstClass*) fMaino;
    else
            main = (MySecondClass*) fMdio;
    ...
    ...
```

And then this is legal

```
    int i = main->GetNum();
```

Actually, proper design (moving the common methods to a base class) will probably eliminate the need for this `if` statement altogether. This is what called the polymorphism, its whole purpose is to eliminate the need for these `if` or `switch` statements.

Comment: Crikey this is almost word-for-word what I was going to post.  You're quick!